# Why is () => Promise<undefined> assignable to () => void?

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this result in a compiler error?

```
function foo(): () => void {
    return () => Promise.resolve();
}
```

This particular case is important, because when a function returns a promise then the caller should know that the function isn't "done" until the promise resolves or rejects.

Promises are related to why this is a problem in the codebase I'm looking at, but it seems the combination of `void` and function types get special treatment in general that I don't understand. Why would the first line in the following error, but not the second line?

```
const y: void = 3;             // error
const x: () => void = () => 3; // OK
```

Am I misunderstanding the phenomenon? Is this a TypeScript bug?

Comment: See the [TypeScript FAQ entry on void-returning functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: Consider using `undefined` as the return type instead of `void` if you care about actually returning `undefined`.  The type `void` means "don't look at the return value", not "there won't be a return value"

Answer (score 4):

As a simple rationale : if you use `() => void` as a callback type, then it means you just won't expect a return value.

You just want to execute a function that takes no argument.

So, since you can also usually invoke functions that returns *something* and then just ignore the returned value, it follows that any function that returns something could be used in place of function marked as returning `void`.

It might be surprising on the point of view of other languages, where the returned type matters for compilation. However, take into account that TypeScript takes roots in JavaScript, and there a function returning "nothing" ( `function f() { return; }`) actually returns `undefined` anyway. So all JS functions return something somehow, in this point of view.

Here is a similar explanation directly from the [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void):

> Another way to think of this is that a void-returning callback type says "I'm not going to look at your return value, if one exists".

So, `void` means "no restriction on the returned type" here.

If you want instead to *forbid* any returned type, then use `() => undefined`, that is the minimal type that will be returned anyway, even by a `void` function.

Comment: I still don't understand this behavior though. Why does `const y: void = 3` but `const x: () => void = () => 3` is OK? If `void` means "don't care" then presumably we don't care for `const y: void = 3` either.

Comment: @MaxHeiber `void` means "don't care", but only in the context of the return value of a function. The example you gave is not a function.

Comment: Another way of putting it is to mentally replace `void` by the word `discarded`  `() => int` can be used if `() => discarded` is expected. But it makes no sense to define a _value variable_ as `discarded` type.

Comment: if  `const x: void = 3`  makes no sense, TS could error when we write it. This also has the benefit of consistent behavior with void-returning functions. Yet I expect the surprising behavior of `const x: void = 3` is intentional and has some explanation. (Also: I voted your answer up)

Comment: @MaxHeiber thanks. I'm not sure to get your comment, though : TS does emit an error for `const x: void = 3`. `void` has meaning only as the return value of a function.

Comment: Note that, for some errors, TypeScript compiler can still emit some JavaScript output. It "compiles with errors" (I find the terms quite confusing). In this case, it will still fallback to the pure untyped JavaScript (`const x = 3;`). See [Example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=18&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoUSEGggB09NAApEydAgCUPXuGgwAHtgBuIfG1IwAzEA). You can fine-tune  the compiler behavior : use `--noEmitOnError` for instance